# Can I hooks and trap events that will occur in android process?

Tags: android

it's possible to hook process in Android?

for example we can hook process in windows:

"trap events that will occur, either in your own process or in other processes. By "hooking", you tell Windows about a function, filter function also called hook procedure, that will be called everytime an event you're interested in occurs"

Please advise , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Hello, it's possible to hook process
>   in Android?

No, sorry.